# Logging off Active Users in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell

I want to programmatically log off all users (except current) which are logged into my system. I already tried the below powershell script to log-off the disconnected users

`C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe | Select-String "Disc" | ForEach{C:\Windows\System32\logoff.exe ($_.toString() -split ' +')[2]}`

I also observed that for Active User when I run below script, I see the **Loaded** property as True(screenshot for same [Loaded=True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKtSY.png)) and False for disconnected user

Is there any way to log-off Active Users ?

Answer (score 0):

Try put this lines of code into a script and run it like that:

**log_off_ad_users.ps1:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\quser.exe | Select-String "Disc" | ForEach{C:\Windows\System32\logoff.exe ($_.toString() -split ' +')[2]}
```

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "C:\log_off_ad_users.ps1"
```

Comment: Do you have this log_off_ad_users.ps1 script which removes all users ?
I am running this code from C# and it works for disconnected users, if you are suggesting to bypass executionpolicy then it is not solving the issue

Comment: look at my edit, this file should contains your lines of code @VirajDharme